# How to convert mod_csrf.c to mod_csrf.so

Tags: webserver, csrf

Help me in converting the mod_csrf.c to mod_csrf.so module. How to compile the c module and what are the configuration needs to be done in the apache webserver. Is there any code needs to be added in my application?

Answer (score 0):

on **ux**:
apxs -i -c mod_csrf.c -lcrypto
apxs -i -A mod_csrf.la
that is explained in the docu : http://mod-csrf.sourceforge.net/
**windows** is different:
best is to use visual studio c++ and add the source there. check google to find vids how to compile apache modules to point to the apache include/modules folders